# Extract email address from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
Francesco Renga <francesco_renga-001@gmail.com>
```

I need to extract only the email, i.e. francesco_renga-001@gmail.com.

How can I do this in nodejs/javascript in "elegant" way?

Comment: You tagged this question with 'regex', this is already an answer to your question : Use a regex.

Comment: @Protectator any help? I am actually learning how to use regex but not find a good solution for cases similar to that one.

Comment: I've written a library that abstracts logic for extracting emails from text. https://github.com/gajus/extract-email-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how to use regex in JavaScript :

```js
var string = "Francesco Renga <francesco_renga-001@gmail.com>"; // Your string containing
var regex = /<(.*)>/g; // The actual regex
var matches = regex.exec(string);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Here's the decomposition of the regex `/<(.*)>/` :

- `/` and `/` are mandatory to define a regex
- `<` and `>` simply matches the two `<` and `>` in your string
- `()` parenthesis "capture" what you're looking for. Here, they get the mail address inside.
- `.*` : `.` means "any character", and `*` means "any number of times. Combined, it means "any character any number of times", and that is inside `<` and `>`, which correspond to the place where the mail is.

Comment: This does not work if string contain more that one person <email>, for example `"Francesco Renga <francesco_renga-001@gmail.com>, Marty McFly <mmcfly@gmail.com>"`

Comment: Not working at all

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working at all" ? If you run the code snippet it works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Using regex, if your string pattern is always `Some text<email>` or `Some text<email>, Some text<email> <email>` you can use this simple one `<(.*?)>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2qKWd/2)

**Other solution**

Use positive lookahead : `[^<]+(?=>)`, here is a snippet and a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2qKWd/4/)

```js
var text = "Francesco Renga <francesco_renga-001@gmail.com>, Marty McFly <mmcfly@gmail.com> Marty McFly <mmcfly@gmail.com> <mmcfly2@gmail.com>";
var re = /[^< ]+(?=>)/g;

text.match(re).forEach(function(email) {
  console.log(email);
});
```

**Explanation**

`[^<]+` match anything but a `<`between one and unlimited times

`(?=>)` followed by a `>`

Simple and does not require any group.

Answer (score 3):

**Here's a simple code showing how extract the unique list of emails address using JavaScript :**

```
let emaillst = string .match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);

            if (emaillst === null) {
                // no Email Address Found
            } else {
                const uniqueEmail = Array.from(new Set(emaillst));
                const finaluniqueEmail = [];
                for(let i=0; i<=uniqueEmail.length; i++){
                    let characterIs = String(uniqueEmail[i]).charAt(String(uniqueEmail[i]).length - 1)
                    if(characterIs==='.'){
                        finaluniqueEmail.push(String(uniqueEmail[i].slice(0, -1)))
                    }else{
                         finaluniqueEmail.push(uniqueEmail[i]);
                    }
                }
                emaillst = finaluniqueEmail.join('\n').toLowerCase();
                console.log(matches[1]);
```

See the Live Demo of  [email address extractor online](https://helpseotools.com/marketing-tools/email-address-extractor)

**Features**

- Get Unique Emails
- Auto remove duplicate emails
- convert upper case email address to lowercase